# ASP.NET bundling - rewrite/transform already minified CSS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using `CssRewriteUrlTransform` because the CSS files I'm bundling contain relative image paths. However, when I run the ASP.NET site on a server, the minified CSS bundle still contains the original image paths (not good). After some debugging I figured out the ASP.NET bundling engine does not minify my CSS file itself, because a `.min.css` file generated by me is already present. So ASP.NET takes that file instead of doing the minification work itself. However, doing so it doesn't seem to run the `CssRewriteUrlTransform`, causing issues with relative image paths.

How can I configure my bundle to run the CSS transform even when ASP.NET decides to take my `.min.css` file? Or do I **have** to remove `.min.css` file to make this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing any `.min.css` file I did not want the bundler to use.